# Update Sharepoint 2007 MySites layout and web parts for already deployed MySites

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint

We are looking to change our users' MySite home pages to make them more useful.  I can find information on how to update the MySite template used to deploy new MySites, but I need to make the changes to 800 sites that have already been created.  I am not having much luck finding details on how to do this.

I am working with Office Sharepoint Server 2007 sp2.